# Observer to only display products if price greater than 0

Tags: magento2, event-observer, magento2.2, catalog

im trying to create an observer to only show products if the price is greater than 0, this is my code, I'm using it for this event "catalog_block_product_list_collection"

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class HideProductsNoPrice implements ObserverInterface
    {
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {    
            $collection = $observer->getData('collection');
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('price',['gt'=>0]);
            return $this;
        }
    }
```

In my events.xml I have the following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_block_product_list_collection">
        <observer name="hide_products_no_price" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\HideProductsNoPrice" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Yet when I list the products I still see all of them, even if their price is 0.00. Am I missing something else? or am I using the wrong event to list the products? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want modify the return or params of a function of Magento, is recommendable use the plugin instead of observer.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

If you want change the results in the catalog product list, you must do the next.

> Vendor/Namespace/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
    <plugin name="vendor_namespace_plugin_list" type="Vendor\Namespace\Plugin\ListProductPlugin"/>
</type>
```

> Vendor/Namespace/Plugin/ListProductPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Namespace\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

/**
 * Class ListProductPlugin
 */
class ListProductPlugin
{

    /**
     * @param ListProduct $subject
     * @param AbstractCollection $resultCollection
     * @return AbstractCollection
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function afterGetLoadedProductCollection(
        ListProduct $subject,
        AbstractCollection $resultCollection
    ) {
        $resultCollection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
        $resultCollection->addAttributeToFilter('price', ['gt' => 0]);

        return $resultCollection;
    }
}
```

You must pay attention with the attribute **price** or **final_price**.

After read your comment, that you use the widgets **catalog product list** and **catalog new product list**, I recommend this.

For the widget catalog product list, the better way is use the conditions in the configuration of the widget. Attach screenshot.
[image]

But, you prefer do it programmatically, you can do this.

> Vendor/Namespace/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList">
     <plugin name="vendor_namespace_plugin_widget_list" type="Vendor\Namespace\Plugin\Widget\ProductListPlugin"/>
</type>
```

> Vendor/Namespace/Plugin/Widget/ProductListPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Namespace\Plugin\Widget;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList;

/**
 * Class ProductListPlugin
 */
class ProductListPlugin
{

    /**
     * @param ProductsList $subject
     * @param Collection $resultCollection
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function afterCreateCollection(
        ProductsList $subject,
        Collection $resultCollection
    ) {
        $resultCollection->addAttributeToFilter('price', ['gt' => 0]);

        return $resultCollection;
    }
}
```

I have reviewed the widget new product list and I have not saw nothing for doing with a plugin, because its methods are protected or privated. I have thought that you can use as condition the attribute **new** and you only show the products which contains the value "yes". It's similar to screenshot attached with the example "price".

Comment: Can you explain me why is the plugin better? Does it have to do with performance or better Magento 2 programming practices? I've used plugins for other things and I really thought for this specific case an observer was more suitable. Thanks in advance

Comment: "With events, there are always multiple objects in play when running the code: The original object generating the event, the event object, the observer object and the EventManager. With a plugin, there is actually one object in the end: The compiled interceptor object. This makes plugins more performant." by https://www.yireo.com/blog/1875-magent-2-observer-or-plugin  .Also You can see this link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/coding-standards/technical-guidelines.html#14-events

Comment: Hi, I just implemented the plugin as you suggested, but the products with price 0 are still showing, btw I'm displaying the products via a widget that I placed in the page, should I display the products via a different way? thanks

Comment: Can you say me the widget code added in the page? May be that the block is different

Comment: Hi I'm using 2 widgets, the 1st widget type I'm using is "Catalog Product List", and the 2nd widget type is "Catalog New Products List" and both of them, are showing the product with price $0.00

Comment: I have updated my answer. @JohnMaldivas

Comment: I tried to do it via the CMS using the conditions you specified and I always got this error: "Error filtering template: Unknown condition operator" but, when I did it programatically as you suggested it worked like a charm, so I'm going to set your answer as the correct one. Thanks a lot for your help. @raumatbel

Comment: Helped me a lot!
Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You filter the collection, but do not pass it on. Try this.

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {    
            $collection = $observer->getData('collection');
            $gtZero = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('price',['gt'=>0]);
            $observer->setData('collection',$gtZero);
            // or $observer->setCollection($gtZero);
            return $this;
        }
```